# Please help me: modify iframe content

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, self-modifying

I want to modify iframe of this source
http://www.mtel.ba/imenik/index.php

I want to hide  
and choose one selected default value from list.

```
<div class="menu-list">
                    <select name="administrative_unit_id">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Svi gradovi</option>
                        <option value='262'>Banja Luka (051)</option><option value='301'>Bijeljina (055)</option>
```

I want to made phone book for one city. is it possible? and how? 
I was try with jquery and file get contents but ....
Thanks

Comment: Is the page you are building on the same domain as the iframe? Or do you have access to the code of mtel.ba?

Comment: You can call the parent page JavaScript function from the iFrame but you cant call the function from parent page to iFrame, there is one way you can archive this feature by creating your own proxy server and you can add your script in that. Let me know if you want to proxy server code.

Comment: No the page its not on same domain? I want to add this base on my page with allways selected my city and want to hide all other cities selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is on the cross domain use proxy page.

Create a new PHP page like that

```
<?php 

echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>'; //insert jquery here

$file = file_get_content('http://www.mtel.ba/imenik/index.php');

echo $file;

echo "<script>";
echo "";//jQuery script here
echo "</script>";
```

Then insert this page as iframe

Comment: I want to hide   <div class="menu-list">
                    <select name="administrative_unit_id">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Svi gradovi</option>
                        <option value='262'>Banja Luka (051)</option> and always choose one selected city. File get content not work, work only get html

Comment: can you provide me "administrative_unit_id" full html and which option in that you want to display and which you want to hide.

Comment: I want to hide all choices and always I want to subscribe value 10000011 for choice. I want to see only input field and search button